# Use a content type's field as a pager item in Views

Tags: 7, views, entities, paging

I'm creating a very custom slideshow with views. It has a content type that has a photo field, some text fields and a thumbnail field. I would like to have my thumbnail field set as the pager items.

I've been messing around with the Views Slideshow plugin, however I don't think it will work in my case because I have my thumbnail's wrapped in a image carousel.

I've been doing some searching and can't find any code/module/example of how to do this.

Alternatively, maybe I could print the field value in the custom page template (outside of the node)?

Any thoughts? I'm using Drupal 7 with the latest version of Views.

Comment: Have you tried the flexslider module? It sounds like it's the thing you're looking for. https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider (I just saw that the question has quite some tumbleweed on it already...)